# Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0 and HTTP 301 Moved Permanently Redirects

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, msxml

I am told that MsXML2 follows redirects. However I get a "HTTP 0" error from the script when accessing a URL that has moved.

The reason I need to make it work is because this is a Windows (Sidebar) Gadget used by 300 000 users. And I am moving the website, and want all calls for old versions to still go through.

This is the code simplified:

```
function MyHttpCall() {
  var httpReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
  httpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpReq.readyState < 4) return;
    if (httpReq.status != 200) alert("HTTP " + httpReq.status);

    alert ("Houston we have contact");
  }

  httpReq.open("GET", myURL, true);
  httpReq.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
  httpReq.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  httpReq.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  httpReq.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Tue, 01 Jan 2008 00:00:00 GMT");
  httpReq.send();
}
```

I assume this has to do with httpReq.status != 200, but I thought the readystatechange is continously firing events once state changes. Fire one for HTTP 301, and another one for HTTP 200.

Comment: How about [Cross-domain Request (XDR)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Accoarding to a Microsoft article, cross-domain redirects are not allowed in MsXML. That could most possibly be the case.